# Using Left without Copy & Paste

Tags: excel, string-formatting, vba

I have some data that I want to be basically cut down to the first 12 numbers no matter how many it goes out. The way I'm currently doing it is taking the numbers from the column C and in Column G I have a formula =Left(C3,12) I then drag down so it matches the range in C. Then I run a macro that looks like this:

```
Sub Macro6()

    Range("G3:G7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

 End Sub
```

This works but I have to constantly update the range, and it's kind of clunky. Does anyone know a better way to accomplish the same thing? (basically making the values in C become the first 12 digits only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your wanting to replace the contents of a cell in column C with the first 12 digits of whatever is in that same cell.

Starting with data that looks like this:

[image]

---

Run This:

```
Sub keep12()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = wks.Range("C3:C" & wks.Range("C" & wks.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Value = Left(cell.Text, 12)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: This one is the closest to what I need. However something gets off on it.
Raw number:
1E+11
1.00003E+11
4E+13
1.50026E+15
1.50026E+17 (This one is 150025752456000000)

 Result:
1E+11
1.00003E+11
4E+13
1.50026E+15
1.50026E+17 (this one becomes 150026000000)

I need this to keep all 12 of the numbers the same from the first 12.

Comment: Here are some of the raw numbers I am working with 100000000000, 100003000000, 40000010000000, 1500257523000000, 150025752456000000. 
I'm not sure why your coding rounds those numbers? When I ran it it. They became 100000000000, 100003000000, 40000000000000, 1500260000000000, 150026000000000000

Comment: I tried it with the actual data you provided and it ran fine without rounding (see my updated pics in the answer).  If I run it with cell formatting as Scientific I see your problem.  My guess is that the scientific notation is loosing the accuracy of the number.  Can you change the cell format to Number instead of Scientific?

Comment: Here is a [download link](http://wikisend.com/download/600362/Truncate.xlsm) using wikisend.com.  I've never used them before.  Looks like the link will be good for 7 days.

Comment: Glad it worked for your purposes.  I'm going to delete the download link shortly since it's only good for a week it won't help others in the future.  Regards.

Comment: If the format is numbers then this works perfectly. I added to the coding:
    
        Columns("C:C").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65610/discussion-between-madchadders-and-portland-runner).

Answer (score 2):

Fastest way! No VBA required.

1. Insert a blank column after Col A.
2. Highlight Col A.
3. Click on Data | text To Columns
4. Select `Fixed Width`
5. Set your field with as shown in the image after 12 characters and click on `Finish`
6. Delete column B (The one we inserted.)

[image]

And here is the output

[image]

Comment: This is a great idea and works, however the problem is I need it to be in VBA specifically (which is why I tagged it that way), so I can take it a step further and use if then statements. Sometimes I need it to be 12 digits and sometimes 10, depending on what is in the column prior to it.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are valid solutions for this as well, with the Excel formula answer being the most efficient way to accomplish it @Siddharth Rout.  I am simply adding another method, that in this case might more directly answer the OP's specific needs, to copy the data from Column C to Column G.

```
Sub LeftFilterAll()

Dim sheetName As String
Dim LastRow As Long

sheetName = "Sheet1"
LastRow = Sheets(sheetName).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row   ' Count the last row in Column C

For row = 2 To LastRow
 'Left 12 From C to G
    Sheets(sheetName).Cells(row, 7).Value = Left(Sheets(sheetName).Cells(row, 3).Text, 12)
Next row

End Sub
```

Down the road, you might want to make it so it simply UPDATES the values in Column G, and doesn't replace them all, if you find you are running this over and over for 1 or two new records, instead of the whole group, you get the last row of column G and start from that row number.  So you'd have the following only updating.  This is no good if you plan on changing values in C after they are entered, as they'd be processed only once.

```
Sub LeftFilterUpdate()

Dim sheetName As String
LastCRow = Sheets(sheetName).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row   ' Count the last row in Column C
LastGRow = Sheets(sheetName).Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row   ' Count the last row in Column G

For row = LastGRow To LastCRow
 'Left 12 From C to G
    Sheets(sheetName).Cells(row, 7).Value = Left(Sheets(sheetName).Cells(row, 3).Text, 12)
Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: This is doing the same thing that @Portland Runner's suggestion is doing. I had raw data numbers 100000000000, 100003000000, 40000010000000, 1500257523000000,  and 150025752456000000 and when it pastes the numbers into G it changes the format to scientific for some reason so they become rounded (100000000000, 100003000000, 40000000000000, 1500260000000000, 150026000000000000). I need it to become (100000000000, 100003000000, 400000100000, 150025752300, 150025752456)

Comment: What you need to do is go into the sheet and select "G" then apply the formatting for the cells on the entire column.  You might want to consider "General" or "Text" instead of numbers.