# How to change the number of digits based on previous column?

Tags: excel, foreach, conditional-formatting, vba

This builds off of this question [Using Left without Copy & Paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098341/using-left-without-copy-paste/27100000?noredirect=1#comment42734638_27100000)

I need to conditionally format these columns depending on the company in the column before. Here is the coding that works:

```
Sub keep12()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = wks.Range("C3:C" & wks.Range("C" & wks.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

'set column C as Number (if this step is skipped it can go to Scientific and that doesn't work)
Columns("C:C").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

For Each Cell In rng
    Cell.Value = Left(Cell.Text, 12)
Next Cell
End Sub
```

basically I want to go one step further and if Column B (company codes) are ABC, DEF, or GHI, then format the cell next to it in C as 10 digits, for any other info in column B (JKL, MNO, etc) then set it as 12. I'm guessing I could use a For Each, Select Case sort of thing? But I'm not entirely sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub keep12()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = wks.Range("C3:C" & wks.Range("C" & wks.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

'set column C as Number (if this step is skipped it can go to Scientific and that doesn't work)
Columns("C:C").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

For Each cell In rng
    Select Case cell.Offset(0, -1)
    Case "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"
        cell.Value = Left(cell.Text, 10)
    Case Else
        cell.Value = Left(cell.Text, 12)
    End Select
Next cell
End Sub
```